# I have Kali installed on a micro SD card for my raspberry pi zero 1.3

Tags: sd-card, linux, pi-zero

I can't get internet in the pi and I need to install a firmware for the internet dongle to work and also make isn't installed. So is there any way I can like boot into the SD card and install and make changes through maybe like VM or something else.

Micro SD has 16 gb

Raspberry pi v1.3

Comment: I got an adapter for Ethernet to USB and connected it to the pi. Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: How does the title refer to the question?

Comment: Could you include details of the adapter and if there was any installation process?

Answer (score 2):

Does the driver need to have a network to install? if not, you can place it under the boot partition and install it.

Also, you can convert your pi zero into a usb dongle and connect it using [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget) tutorial by adafruit. From that link:

> you can tunnel networking, VNC, ssh and scp files, etc. Basically you get the ability to log in to the console as well as anything else you could want to do over a network connection
>   Note that even though it's called "Ethernet Gadget" you do not use an Ethernet cable! The only cable is the USB micro-B cable from your computer to your Pi Zero. The Pi 'appears' like an Ethernet device.
>   You can even share your desktop computer's network setup so your Pi can access the internet through your computer via the USB cable! Cool huh?

Answer (score 0):

I'm understanding that you have a wifi adapter that isn't supported, and you're trying to add the drivers. Easiest will be to boot the same card on a RPi that does have Internet connectivity. Otherwise, you're going to have to figure out how to download the drivers and copy them onto the card for installation. In any case, you're going to require a working network connection. You could just use a supported wifi adapter on your RPi Zero 1.3 (e.g. Edimax, TP-Link and other low-cost solutions) to do all of this, then swap adapters once you have the necessary drivers working. I did this early on when the TP-Link adapters weren't well supported. I'd boot with a supported Edimax adapter, load and configure everything, then swap the Edimax for the TP-Link.

Comment: I have the TP-Link WN722N V.2 and it requires the rtl8188eu driver in order to work. Ill need to return it because the V.1 has an older firmware so if you plug it in it works with all OS's. I can try getting another dongle or putting the firmware onto the card but there's a bigger problem. If I do that I wouldn't be able to make and make install because it tells me that make isn't installed. Is there something I'm missing or some other program that works like make already installed on Kali raspberry image? If worse comes to worse I'll make into a USB dongle. But until then anything I can do?

Comment: What I'd suggest is getting your RPi working with a supported network connection. For a Zero 1.3, one of the ubiquitous Edimax or other well-supported adapters is a good idea. With a functioning network, download and install your build environment (including make - e.g. apt install build-essential), compile and install the driver, then swap USB network adapters and see if you can get the new version working. Also, check on the RPi forums to see if somebody has done the work for you. I frequently had to do this with TP-Link adapters back when the RPi was new. USB gadget mode is an alternative.